# What do you call the narrated part of an introduction?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the narrated part of an introduction?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRaoYuRKBaA

I am talking about the narrated part before the song plays. Is there a word for it? In a novel, it's called a prologue, but I am not sure if it's also called a prologue or not.

Comment: "narration"?  It's not really part of the song, but perhaps an "introduction"

Comment: There certainly is a term for it, but it's industry-specific, and nobody outside the industry is likely to know. Seems like a good question for https://movies.stackexchange.com/. I don't know how to migrate a question to another stack exchange, but probably someone else does